# Working with strings in GCP-Workflows and GCP-Admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk, google-workflows

I'm integrating a project in GCP-Workflows with GCP-Admin, but I'm having trouble working with some data, when extracting a date it is delivered in this format: `2020-12-28T11: 20: 05.000Z`, so I can't turn the `string` into `int`, and apparently there is no function in GCP like `substring()` either. I need to use the date with an IF, checking if it is greater or less than the reference.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some lack of function implementation for now in Workflows. New ones are coming very soon. But I don't know if they will solve your problem

Anyway, with workflows, the correct pattern, if a built-in function isn't implemented, is to call an endpoint, for example a Cloud Function or a Cloud Run, which perform the transformation for you and return the expected result.

Quite boring to do, but don't hesitate to [open feature request on the issues tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) product team is very reactive and love user feedbacks!

Answer (score 0):

The Workflows standard library now includes a [text module](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/overview#module:-text) with functions for searching (including regular expressions), splitting, substrings and case transformations.